# choose path of database or let install continue

Tags: inno-setup

I try to do something in InnoSetup but I can not. I would like to let the user to choose whether to install a database or to select a path for this one.

To be more specific, I would have a page with my 2 components:
"Standard" and "Server"

**Case 1 :**
If the user selected "standard", the installation continues normally and install the database locally.

**Case 2 :**
If the user selected "server", the next page is for select the base path (eg a network share) and do not install the database locally.

I begin with Inno Setup (especially for the code section) How do I get to do that?

Here's an example of my current code and note that I have tried to adapt the codes found on the internet to my problem but it is not necessarily appropriate :

```
[Types]
Name: "standard"; Description: "Local Database";
Name: "server"; Description: "Server Database"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "baselocal"; Description: "Standard Installation : install program and local database"; Types: standard; 
Name: "baseserver"; Description: "Installation with server database : install program and choose directory for database"; Types: server;

[Files]
Source: "Path\to\database\*"; DestDir: "{app}\{code:GetDir|0}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Components: standard

[Code]
// Database choice
var
  DirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
  DirPageID: Integer;

function GetDir(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result := DirPage.Values[StrToInt(Param)];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  // create a directory input page
  DirPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectComponents, 'Choix de la base', 'Caneco BT peut gérer une base sur un serveur ou en local. Veuillez indiquez le chemin de la base qui vous intéresse.', 'Dossier Base de Données', False, '');
  // add directory input page items
  DirPage.Add('Sélectionnez un chemin :');
  // assign default directories for the items from the previously stored data; if
  // there are no data stored from the previous installation, use default folders
  // of your choice
  DirPage.Values[0] := GetPreviousData('Directory1', ExpandConstant('{pf}\program\'));
  DirPageID := DirPage.ID;
end;

procedure RegisterPreviousData(PreviousDataKey: Integer);
begin
  // store chosen directories for the next run of the setup
  SetPreviousData(PreviousDataKey, 'Directory1', DirPage.Values[0]);
end;
// Skip page
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  // initialize result to not skip any page (not necessary, but safer)
  Result := False;
  // if the page that is asked to be skipped is your custom page, then...
  if PageID = DirPageID then
    // if the component is not selected, skip the page
    Result := not IsComponentSelected('help');
end;
```

thank you in advance

Comment: What about user interface [`like this`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni6yD.png) ?

Comment: I think it would go, I'll try this (thx @TLama for save me a second times ^^)

Comment: @TLama Ok it works well, but there are a few things that bother me:
the next button it can be gray as it is nothing selected?
I can only select files, then I would select a folder
and copy the path to this folder in a registry key. How i can do that ?

Comment: Something [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/8842NK85) ?

Comment: Yes that's it :) but when i select "Option with no file selection" i can't continue :(

Comment: Oh, I missed that the directory edit box must contain a valid directory to allow you to continue. Well, this attempt won't work with the directory page. Forget it. Sorry...

Comment: Ok, no problem. And can we make a mix of this 2 solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I started to zero and therefore tried to do something like this:

```
[code]
var
  ActionPage: TInputOptionWizardPage;
  DirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
  DirPageID: Integer;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  ActionPage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome,
    'Optional Actions Test', 'Which actions should be performed?',
    'Please select all optional actions you want to be performed, then click Next.',
    True, False);

  ActionPage.Add('Action 1');
  ActionPage.Add('Action 2');

  ActionPage.Values[0] := True;
  ActionPage.Values[1] := False;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = ActionPage.ID then begin
    if ActionPage.Values[0] then
                begin
                  // create a directory input page
                  DirPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectComponents, 'Choix de la base', 'Caneco BT peut gérer une base sur un serveur ou en local. Veuillez indiquez le chemin de la base qui vous intéresse.', 'Dossier Base de Données', False, '');
                  // add directory input page items
                  DirPage.Add('Sélectionnez un chemin :');
                  // assign default directories for the items from the previously stored data; if
                  // there are no data stored from the previous installation, use default folders
                  // of your choice
                  DirPage.Values[0] := GetPreviousData('Directory1', ExpandConstant('{pf}\program\'));
                  DirPageID := DirPage.ID;
                  exit;
                end;

    if ActionPage.Values[1] then
       MsgBox('Local Database', mbInformation, MB_OK);
       exit;
  end;
end;
```

That's working (and i'm very happy for that) but i have a problem :

If I select "Action1" and I'm going to the "DirPage" page and then I go back, select "Action 2" the "DirPage" page appears.

Otherwise, if I select from the start "Action2" the page "DirPage" does not appear as expected.

Why? Is can I fix this?